# gunicorn с flask через функцию, деплой на Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, gunicorn

Мне необходимо создать Flask сервер из функции (на самом деле это будет метод в классе) Локально все работает(без gunicorn), но на сервере через gunicorn не работает.

Пробовал много разных вариантов, вот один из них.

Модуль test.py

```
def serv():
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
        return "<h1 style='color:red'>Hello world!</h1>"
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
    
    return app
```

wsgi.py

```
from test import serv

if __name__ == "__main__":
    serv().run()
```

Локально без gunicorn все работает. Однако, на heroku через gunicorn возвращает 503 ошибку. Если убрать функцию и импортировать без функции, все начинает работать даже с более простым кодом.

К сожалению, не хватает опыта разобраться. Как мне добиться запуска Flask через функцию при работе с gunicorn.

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.

Для вызова flask из функции, необходимо указывать об этом в явном виде при запуске gunicorn.
Например с Heroku в Procfile указать название функции

```
web: gunicorn "wsgi:servflask()"
```

При указании функции ковычки являются обязательными.

file wsgi.py

```
from test import servflask

if __name__ == "__main__":
    servflask().run()
```

test.py

```
def servflask():
    from flask import Flask
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
        return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"
    
    return app
```

Answer (score 0):

Project structure:

```
test_app
├── app.py
└── __init__.py
```

`__init__.py` is empty

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<h1 style='color:red'>Hello world!</h1>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

cmd to run:

`gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:5000 --access-logfile=- "test_app.app:app"`

Comment: Задача запустить Flask функцией. Если из моего примера убрать функцию, то тоже все заработает. Но мне нужно вызвать Flask из функции.